# Replace part of URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I want to replace part of the URL with JavaScript but stupid regex is giving me headaches. I want to switch from this:

```
http://website.com/test.html/post/something-else/
```

to this:

```
http://website.com/post/something-else/
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What regexs have you tried

Comment: @Gus: `url.replace(/\/test.html([^\/]+)$/, "\/$1");`, `var parts = url.split('/');
    var img = parts.pop().replace("test.html", "");
    parts.push(img)
    url = parts.join("/");`

Comment: Do you only want to remove "test.html" or are there more variants?

Comment: @QuentinUK: no, only "test.html". I’m redirecting every page there.

Comment: "only 'test.html'" and "redirecting every page" seem to be opposites. Which do you mean?

Comment: @Gus: I’m forwarding every page from my subdomain to `http://website.com/test.html/XXXX` and there I want the `test.html` removed from the URL. From there I redirect the user to the page without the subdomain (handled by forwarding) and `test.html` (I want this removed with JS) in the URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use replace() function

```
var url = 'http://website.com/test.html/post/something-else/'
url = url.replace('/test.html','')
console.log(url) // "http://website.com/post/something-else/"
```

Comment: there was a mistake. sorry. I edit answer and code works well now: http://tinker.io/9f60a/1

Comment: Tinker.io links are 404.