# Split url with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to split the following url:

```
http://www.store.com/products.aspx/Books/The-happy-donkey
```

in order to get only `http://www.store.com/products.aspx`

I'm using JavaScript `window.location.href` and `split` but not success so far.

How can this be done? thanks!

Comment: Firstly look at this question, it maybe helpfull for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534673/replace-part-of-url-with-javascript
is it?

Comment: is it specifically for the url only, or do you intend to use the function generically... as in, what if you just remove the "/Books/The-Happy-donkey" part?

Comment: The "/Books/The-Happy-donkey" is dynamic, so the only reference i have  is the .aspx part, but with split is doing no good

Comment: @GlenSwift actually no... I need the whole page until .aspx so i can connect into a webMethod :(

Comment: Hi, I'm finding it hard to understand your question, would you mind adding more inputs with expected output? It's hard to induce from a single example with this description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var fullurl = "http://www.store.com/products.aspx/Books/The-happy-donkey",
    url = fullurl.split(".aspx")[0] + ".aspx";
```

Comment: Smart and effective

Answer (score 4):

In the case of a url: http://www.store.com/products.aspx/Books/The-happy-donkey from the address bar

```
 var path = window.location.pathname;
 var str = path.split("/");
 var url = document.location.protocol + "//" + document.location.hostname + "/" + str[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't unwieldy, is it?

```
var url = 'http://www.store.com/products.aspx/Books/The-happy-donkey';

[
    url.split('://')[0] + '://', 
    url.split('://')[1].split('/').slice(0,2).join('/')
].join('')
```

A little less cheeky:

```
url.split('/').slice(0, 4).join('/')
```

Answer (score 1):

The better answer (than split) is probably with a regex honestly unless you just REALLY need to use split (for the fun of it):

```
var shorterUrl = window.location.href.replace(/\.aspx.+/gi, ".aspx");
```

this replaces the end of your given url, starting at .aspx and just keeps the .aspx part.

But foremost, this is not a good solution tactic to a specific problem (try to solve problems like this more generically).

Answer (score 0):

try this, you would get object of url

```
console.log(new URL(document.URL));
```